# Solving Geoserver - No service: ( ows ) - exception

Tags: geoserver, nginx

I have an application running on PHP which makes an AJAX request to a OWS service.

The OWS service is provided by GeoServer running on Tomcat and protected with a Nginx reverse proxy

The condition specified in nginx is:

```
location ~ /geoserver/MY_WORKSPACE(.*) {

    valid_referers server_name mydomain1 mydomain2;

    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }

    proxy_set_header "attribute" "value";
    proxy_pass http://localhost:81/geoserver/MY_WORKSPACE$1;
}
```

Based on the referrer (domains allowed) the Ngnix reverse proxy lets the request pass or not.

The request is a full ows request `https://mydomain2.com/geoserver/MY_WORKSPACE/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=getFeature&typeName=MY_LAYER&maxFeatures=3000&transparent=true&outputFormat=application%2Fjson`

Without the condition in the reverse proxy the request gets back the json data flawesly.

With the condition instead of getting back my JSON file what I get from GeoServer is a XML document (status code 200) with the following information:

`<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows https://mydomain2.com/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="service">
    <ows:ExceptionText>No service: ( ows )</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>`

Comment: Check from the GeoServer logs what kind of wrong requests are coming in. Obviously at least parameter SERVICE= is missing.

Comment: most likely error is not passing on the request parameters

Comment: What is the actual request made by application?

Comment: A request like `https://mydomain.com/geoserver/ows?` will give that exception response, but GeoServer is expecting request parameters as well, like `https://mydomain.com/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=...&...`

Comment: I've edited the question.. Please see the full request made. But I strongly believe it has nothing to do with the request but with the reverse proxy. Without any filtering in the reverse proxy, every thing works fine.

Comment: Can you upload your Nginx configuration for the reverse proxy, as @IanTurton states the issue is no parameters getting through, which means there is something wrong in your Nginx configuration.

Comment: I have uploaded the configuration, please see it in the question above mentioned. The condition works, I get a response with status code 200. But the problem is that the response is the xml file (with the no service ows error) and not the json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of failed trials, I found what the problem was. The error was the regex in the location context.

Since I want to match these url/requests:

`https://mydomain2.com/geoserver/MY_WORKSPACE_AB/ows?service.....`

`https://mydomain2.com/geoserver/MY_WORKSPACE_CD/ows?service.....`

`https://mydomain2.com/geoserver/MY_WORKSPACE_EF/ows?service.....`

the nginx location can be simply specified as

```
location /geoserver/MY_WORKSPACE {

    valid_referers server_name mydomain1;

    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }

    proxy_set_header "attribute" "value";
    proxy_pass http://localhost:81/geoserver/MY_WORKSPACE;
}
```

There is no need of regexs...

Hope it helps someone

Cheers